# How to free the memory allocted in *.dll

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, dll, memory-leaks

> I think I need to describe my problem more clearly:
>
> the called dll will manage its memory only on the heap. the calling
>   part is managing its memory on the stack. And the calling part have no
>   access to the dll memory allocating information. So when I call the
>   deconstruct function like "~UserVideoAbstration". It can not release the
>   memory allocated on the heap.
>
> It is a problem related to the *.dll inner implementation

I am doing a project, there are 2 parts, one is packing the key algorithms implementation to a *.dll file. I encapsulate the algorithm part to a object implementation.

```
class UserVideoAbstraction{ 
private:
    VideoAbstraction *userVB;
public:
    __declspec(dllexport) UserVideoAbstraction(const char* inputpath, const char* videoname, const char* midname);
    __declspec(dllexport) UserVideoAbstraction();
    __declspec(dllexport) ~UserVideoAbstraction();

    __declspec(dllexport) void UserAbstraction(Mat& currentFrame, int frameIndex);          //进行背景减除的函数
    __declspec(dllexport) int UsersaveConfigInfo();
```

In the constructor function, I write like this:

```
UserVideoAbstraction::UserVideoAbstraction(const char* inputpath, const char* videoname,const  char* midname)
{
    string t1=inputpath;
    string t2=videoname;
    string t3=midname;
    userVB =new VideoAbstraction(t1,t2,t3);
}
```

So you know, when I am calling the *.dll, it will allocate memory. The calling part is the second part of the project, it is a .Net based windows implementation, but I find in the second part,

> It is useless to offer such deconstruct function

```
UserVideoAbstraction::~UserVideoAbstraction(){
    delete userVB;
};
```

So I am wondering whether you have some good solution for this problem .

---

The application implementation part introduce ...

It is normal C++ implementation, the calling part is a control button implementation (of .Net)with C++.

Just like that :

```
//initial part
UserVideoAbstraction use(inputpath, videoname, midname);

//deconstruct part 
use.~UserVideoAbstration();
```

Comment: You do know that doing `delete` on a pointer to an object, the objects destructor will be automatically called? Also, you don't *call a dll*, instead you create an instance of the `UserVideoAbstraction` class, and that creation will call the class constructor, which allocates memory.

Comment: Maybe it's different in your actual code, but with your example, I don't see the need for userVB to be a pointer at all.

Comment: In fact, it is useless to call the deconstruct function. Maybe it is because that the second part has no right to free the memory allocated in the *.dll part. You can call the deconstruct function explicitly, but it is useless. The memory are not released successfully.

Comment: You **should use** `std::string` since you are programming in C++ not in C

Comment: @PianoCoder The UserVideoAbstraction destructor is still part of the .dll - when that code is it should reference the dll private heap if there's any. Also if your dll is linked to the same runtime as the application using the dll, you do not have the problem of the application and the dll working with different heaps. So, the only real problem is you're calling the destructor of VideoAbstraction twice.  If there is a problem, describe how you discovered it.

Comment: @nos Yes, it seems that the memory allocted in the dll part is on the heap, but in the .Net part(calling part), the deconstruct function is useless and it produce heavy memory leak problem.

Comment: @PianoCoder In your question, please include the code in the calling application that manages its instance of `UserVideoAbstraction`.

Comment: @ChrisCulter Ok, I will post it later , the calling application part is controlled by my colleges, thanks for your advice .

Comment: @PianoCoder Why is it useless ? Since you're managing resources, your .NET code should .dispose() your object, and you should have code that gets called on .dispose() to call your destructor. Or you wrap your class as is described e.g. here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235281.aspx . Since your problem is as much about .NET (C# ?) as it is about C++, i suggest you tell us more about how you're using your C++ code in .NET ...

Comment: @nos  Ok, I will post it later , the calling application part is controlled by my colleges, thanks for your advice .

Comment: @nos  I think I need to describe my problem more clearly:

the called dll will manage its memory only on the heap. the calling part is managing its memory on the stack. And the calling part have no access to the dll memory allocating information. So when I call the deconstruct function offered by the system. It can not release the memory allocated on the heap.

It is a problem related to the *.dll inner implementation

Comment: @PianoCoder If that's the way things are done, the UserVideoAbstraction destructor you've posted will take care of it when the UserVideoAbstraction you've allocated on the stack goes out of scope.

Answer (score 0):

You should call not manually call the destructor.

```
UserVideoAbstraction::~UserVideoAbstraction(){
    delete userVB;
};
```

However, it is better to use `std::tr1::shared_ptr<VideoAbstraction>` instead of a raw pointer, then you do not have to manually delete it. (You can use `std::shared_ptr<>` in `C++11`)

Or not make it a pointer at all, with `userVB` of the type `VideoAbstraction`:

```
UserVideoAbstraction::UserVideoAbstraction(const char* inputpath, const char*  videoname,const  char* midname)
 : t1( inputpath ),
   t2( videoname ),
   t3( midname ),
   userVB( inputpath, videoname, midname )
{}
```

Comment: If you do not call the delete function manually, it will not release the memory. It is because I have packed all the class into a dll file.Besides that, I find that in the .Net frame, the deconstruct function is useless.

Comment: I'd say a unique pointer is a better solution, and such things are no longer in tr1 if you have C++11.

Comment: Thanks for your advice, I find that it is because the problem is cross different platform, some people have also met the similar problem. In the windows operation plat form implementation, it can not release the memory allocated in the called dll part.  @OMGtechy

Answer (score 0):

I just explicitly define a function doing the similar task as the deconstruct function to release the memory of the object, the memory allocated is freed successfully.

Here is my solution , the first part is

```
void VideoAbstraction::freeObject(){
    videoCapture.~VideoCapture();
    videoWriter.~VideoWriter();
    backgroundImage.release();              
    currentStartIndex.release();
    currentEndIndex.release();
    mog.~BackgroundSubtractorMOG2();
    .............
}
```

the encapsulation part is redesigned like that

```
__declspec(dllexport) void UserfreeObject();// declaration part 

//implementation part
void UserVideoAbstraction::UserfreeObject(){
        userVB->freeObject();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From the comments it appears you think the problem is due to .NET garbage collector not deterministically deleting the C++ object in the dll. This is wrong. Whilst .NET will create the object using its constructor, eventually the destructor will be called. Eventually. At this point, the same process will be performed by the .NET code, in that a call will happen to free the memory used by the object - and in this cased, that call will be the object destructor.

The rule is simple: encapsulate everything in the C++ class, what you allocate in the constructor, you free in the deconstructor.

If you're writing a C++/CLI class, then you may want to use the finaliser syntax for the destructor (sigh, Microsoft.. why) which [uses the ! symbol](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177197%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) before the class name (eg `UserVideoAbstraction::!UserVideoAbstraction`). If you're using P/Invoke style interop, then stop it now, its not compatible with C++ objects anyway and woudl be the reason your destructor is not called automatically - though I guess you could put an explicit call to the destructor in your dispose or finaliser.

Comment: I think I need to describe my problem more clearly:

the called dll will manage its memory only on the heap. the calling part is managing its memory on the stack. And the calling part have no access to the dll memory allocating information. So when I call the deconstruct function offered by the system. It can not release the memory allocated on the heap.

It is a problem related to the *.dll inner implementation

Comment: @PianoCoder nope, you still need to describe the problem clearly. If the called dll allocates memory, then its destructor needs to free that memory. Where the object is created is irrelevant. So the caller creates an object on the stack, and the object then allocates memory internally on the heap. When the object goes out of scope, its dtor will be called automatically, which will free the memory the ctor allocated. I don't understand what the "deconstruct function offered by the system" is.

Comment: @gbjaanb I mean that default deconstruct function.

Comment: @PianoCoder what I said applies then - the object created on the stack is only the object, not what it allocates during its operation. So the dtor will be called automatically. Think of the object as a black box, as far as the caller is concerned, it knows nothing about what happens inside the box. As long as your dtor code cleans up what you did in the ctor, you're good. If the ctor could allocate memory, then the dtor can free it just the same.